# Is there a verb for "created" but for policies?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb for "created", but for policies? I am not sure, but "created" doesn't sound right when used with policies, so I thought of "came up", but it's too informal, so I am not sure if there's a proper verb for it.

For example:

> The economic policy was ___ by the current chief economist of the
>   World Bank.

Written sounds off too, because I want to say "created, imagined", but all these verbs also seems to be inappropriate with the word "policy".

Comment: established....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb I most often see in this context is "drafted". Strictly speaking, it means "wrote the initial version of the document in which the policy is expressed".

> The Jones administration drafted its new trade policy.

By metaphor, the creation of the policy document is extended to mean the creation of the policy itself.

One could also use

> - thought of
> - came up with
> - devised
> - invented
> - created

there are shades of meaning that differ among these verbs, but any can be used to mean the creation of a policy or any other idea.